# What is the difficulty with ORDER BY and UNION in MS Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the difficulty with `ORDER BY`?
`UNION` is not supporting here.

Showing

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

```
Select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID > 0) as X 
                   where ID > z  Order By ID desc
UNION 
 select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID < 10) as X 
                   where ID < z  Order By ID asc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one `order by` clause for the query.  Since `union` produces one result set, that shouldn't be an issue anyway -- just place it at the end.

```
Select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID > 0) as X 
               where ID > z  
UNION 

select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID < 10) as X 
               where ID < z  

ORDER BY ID asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
Select  Top 2 
        * 
from    (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    xxx 
            WHERE ID > 0
        ) as X 
where   ID > z 
UNION   
select  Top 2 
        * 
from    (
            SELECT * 
            FROM xxx 
            WHERE ID < 10
        ) as X 
where   ID < z 
Order By ID asc
```

Have a look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and look specifically at the TSQL Syntax

Transact-SQL

```
<SELECT statement> ::=  

    [WITH <common_table_expression> [,...n]]
    <query_expression> 
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] } 
  [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ COMPUTE 
  { { AVG | COUNT | MAX | MIN | SUM } (expression )} [ ,...n ] 
  [ BY expression [ ,...n ] ] 
    ] 
    [ <FOR Clause>] 
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ] 

<query_expression> ::= 
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ] 

<query_specification> ::= 
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] 
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ] 

    < select_list > 
    [ INTO new_table ] 
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ] 
    [ <GROUP BY> ] 
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

Note the section `<query_expression>` with 0/1 `ORDER BY` clause.

where the `<query_expression>` is defined futher below with `UNION` section.

Comment: Thanx astander. But i wouldn't get expected results. I want get two ID's before and two ID's after for a given ID.

Comment: You might then rather tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve, so that we can assist you in that.

Comment: Posted query reulting the same.

Comment: I got it..! Solution is Select * from ( Select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID > 0) as X  
                   where ID > z  Order By ID desc 
UNION  
 select Top2 * from(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ID < 10) as X  
                   where ID < z  Order By ID asc 
) as X